# MYSQL Toplist by the sum of teammember points

Tags: mysql, sum

So i would like to make a toplist in mysql.
I have two table, users and teams.

In users I have: id,name,points,teamid

In teams I have: t_id,teamname,leaderid

I would like to make a toplist. The 10 teams with the most points.

I hope it is understandable what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the total sum of points by using the subquery which will give you the top 10 points then join this result with a query which has team information with the sum of points for each team,from this approach if there is tie in scores of 2 teams they will be included in top 10 teams regarding the points

```
select t2.* from 
(select t.*,sum(u.points) allpoints
 from teams t
join users u
on(t.t_id= u.teamid)
group by t.t_id
) t2
join
(select sum(points) allpoints 
   from users 
   group by teamid 
   order by allpoints desc 
  limit 10) tp
on(t2.allpoints = tp.allpoints )
```

if you don't care for tie scenario you can simply use limit and order by

```
select t.*,sum(u.points) allpoints
     from teams t
    join users u
    on(t.t_id= u.teamid)
    group by t.t_id
    order by allpoints desc
    limit 10
```